# Updating mutable HashMap in a while loop

Tags: rust, immutability, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement Karger's algorithm in Rust and I have run into an issue while trying to update a mutable hashmap in a while loop.

The map is updated successfully, but then in the next iteration when it was cloned, the values that were updated don't seem to have been changed. However removing elements from the map is reflected on later iterations.

I have tried debugging and printing the values of the map, but the sequence of events doesn't make sense to me.

```
use itertools::Itertools;  // 0.8.0
use rand::seq::{IteratorRandom, SliceRandom}; // 0.6.5
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn contract_edge(graph: &mut HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>, num_trials: i32) {
    let mut count = 0;

    while graph.len() > 2 && count < num_trials {
        // clone graph so I can mutate graph later
        let imut_graph = graph.clone();

        // choose random node
        let from_value = imut_graph
            .keys()
            .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
            .unwrap()
            .clone();
        let values = imut_graph.get(&from_value);
        let to_value = values
            .unwrap()
            .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
            .unwrap()
            .clone();

        let from_edges = imut_graph[&from_value].iter().clone();

        // accessing to_value in imut_graph gives error here later
        let to_edges = imut_graph[&to_value]
            .iter()
            .clone()
            .filter(|&x| *x != from_value && *x != to_value);

        let new_edges = from_edges.chain(to_edges);

        // since I am mutating the graph I thought the next time is is clone it would be updated?
        graph.insert(from_value, new_edges.map(|v| v.clone()).collect());
        graph.remove(&to_value);
        for (_key, val) in graph.iter_mut() {
            *val = val
                .iter()
                .map(|v| if v == &to_value { &from_value } else { v })
                .unique()
                .cloned()
                .collect();
        }
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

When I try to access the map, I get element not found error, but the keys which have been removed should not exist in the vector values at that point.

I am convinced this is something I don't understand about (Im)mutability in Rust.

Comment: What do you believe that the `clone` method does? Why do you think it is required to "clone graph so I can mutate graph later"?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MCVE]. Your code compiles, but doesn't include code that demonstrates the problem, such as an example main. It would make it much easier for us to help if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for looking, I think that clone is making an immutable copy of the map? 
This is required because when I try to access the map contents and then later mutate it, I get an error. 

In my understanding I should be cloning the now mutated map, so the values in the clone should be updated?

Comment: @ThomasC did you have a chance to look at the provided answer?  How is that not satisfying your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, but based on what I can see above, that is, you'd like to mutate your original `graph` (because you are passing that as a mutable borrow to your function) and that you don't have a return value, and that your question is about mutating a hashmap -- I assume that you'd like the changes to be reflected in your original `HashMap`.  So why are you cloning it in the first place then?

If on the other hand you don't want to mutate your original object, then don't pass it in as a mutable borrow, but as an immutable one.  Then create a clone of it before you start the loop and use that cloned version throughout your algorithm.

The problem you are facing with is happening because on every iteration you are cloning the original `graph` and not your cloned `imut_graph`, i.e. on every iteration you create a new `HashMap`, which then you are mutating, then you start a new cycle and you are still checking the length of the original one and then you clone the original one again.

So the two options you have are:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn mutated(map: &mut HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>) {
    map.insert(1, vec![4, 5, 6]);
}

fn cloned(map: &HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>) -> HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>> {
    let mut map = map.clone();
    map.insert(2, vec![7, 8, 9]);
    map
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(0, vec![1, 2, 3]);

    println!("{:?}", cloned(&map));

    mutated(&mut map);
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Which will give you:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3], 2: [7, 8, 9]}
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer let me see that I was cloning the original map each time. I now just clone the original and pass it in as a parameter to the function.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad if my answer was any help!